# Joining and combining MySQL tables from Informix

Tags: mysql, informix

I previously asked this in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703444/joining-mysql-and-informix-tables), But I couldn't find a solution, so I thought I'd share my problem here too.
I have an old system that uses Informix for data storage, and I'm working on migrating such system, which includes migrating the data to a MySQL server.

What I need to do is allow some old subsystems to query some data already stored in MySQL (corresponding to subsystems in production), and combine it with their Informix tables.

So I find myself in the need to combine MySQL and Informix tables (joins in particular), and I have no idea how to proceed.
I tried querying MySQL, and building a temporary table in Informix with the recovered data, but there are more than 4000 rows, and the insert queries are too slow.